# PSAD выдает ошибку

Tags: linux, fedora

имеем Fedora 31, недавно обратил внимание после перехода с версии на версию систмы, что появилось в fw_check сообщение

```
[-] You may just need to add a default logging rule to the
'filter' 'INPUT' chain on maint.maintlab.ru. For more information,
see the file "README" in the psad sources directory or visit:

http://www.cipherdyne.org/psad/docs/fwconfig.html
```

[-] You may just need to add a default logging rule to the
    'filter' 'FORWARD' chain on maint.maintlab.ru. For more information,
    see the file "README" in the psad sources directory or visit:

```
http://www.cipherdyne.org/psad/docs/fwconfig.html
```

В качестве firewall у меня стоит по старинке iptables, все пакеты протоколируются в отдельном файле /var/log/iptables.log

В firewall описаны правила, вроде как рекомендуется в документации psad

> $IPTABLES -A INPUT -j LOG
>
> $IPTABLES -A FORWARD -j LOG
>
> $IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $INET_IFACE -j LOG --log-level info --log-prefix "Inbound:"
>
> $IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i $INET_IFACE  -j LOG --log-prefix "DROP:" --log-ip-options --log-tcp-options --log-level info

В psad.conf

> AUTO_DETECT_JOURNALCTL      N;
>
> ENABLE_SYSLOG_FILE          Y;
>
> IPT_SYSLOG_FILE             /var/log/iptables.log;

Пробовал в AUTO_DETECT_JOURNAL ставить Y Все равно не помогает. Кто знает проблему?

Answer (score 0):

проблема решилась. Если используется iptables файервол, вместо стандартного для Fedora firewalld нужно в конфигурацию psad.conf изменить следующие параметры

```
ENABLE_OVERRIDE_FW_CMD      Y;
```

> FW_CMD                      /usr/sbin/iptables;